# Hide/Don't list non-readable folders

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, directory

In a multi-user environment using Ubuntu server 14.04 as a shared drive

All users connect via SFTP using Filezilla/WinSCP and are chroot to `/home/company-folder/`

Each user has also its own personal folder under `/home/company-folder/users/`. Eg. `/home/company-folder/users/username-1`, `/home/company-folder/users/username-2` and so on...

Now `username-1` can see other users personal folders (`/home/company-folder/users/username-2`, `/home/company-folder/users/username-3`, etc), he cannot access other user folders but he can see them listed.

Question is: what can I do so users cannot see each others personal directory under `/home/company-folder/users/`?
Is there anyway in Ubuntu-Linux to hide non-readable folders?

Since in a system with 100+ users is not convenient for users to browse through the whole list of user folders to find his personal folder.

Comment: In general, no. Only the permission of the *parent directories* determine, whether its content can be listed by a particular user.

Comment: Samba may be another option, that can definitely do something to that effect, if CIFS is a viable file access protocol for you case. On the other hand, I don't see, what's so bad about listing all user homes to everyone. This has the advantage, that users may share a subset of their files with other users.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. Only the permission of the (from your point of view) *parent* directories determine, whether its content can be listed by a particular user. This includes directory entries, that this user cannot open/read. The mechanism for SSH/SFTP access is the same as with local tools, since the SSH/SFTP server spawns a subprocess for each session and changes the ownership of the subprocess to the respective user, as soon as they're authenticated successfully.

Consider the following example:

```
david@localhost:~$ ls -la /home
dr-xr-xr-x  1  root   root    80 Nov 10 09:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 23  root   root  4,0K Dec 17 11:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x  1 guest  guest   836 Sep  4 20:58 guest
drwxr-x---  1 david  users  4,2K Dec 14 22:07 david
drwx------  1  root   root   614 Nov 10 12:42 root
```

As you can see, I, `david`, can list the content of `/home` even though I am not its owner, since everybody can read it (see the permission mask in front of the `.` entry). I can list the content of `/home/guest` for the same reason. I can also list the content of `/home/david`, since I'm its owner and the owner has read permission. However, I cannot list the content of `/home/root`, since I'm not the owner and nobody but the owner has read permissions on that directory:

```
david@localhost:~$ ls /home/root
ls: cannot open directory /home/root: Permission denied
```

If one changed the ownership of `/home` to remove read permission for non-owners, I could not list the content of `/home` any longer:

```
david@localhost:~$ sudo chmod o-r /home
david@localhost:~$ ls -ld /home
drwxr-x--x 2 root root 40 Dez 17 21:17 /home
david@localhost:~$ ls -l /home
ls: cannot open directory /home: Permission denied
```

Though, I can still traverse `/home` and read `/home/david`, because the traverse permission (that's the semantic of the “execute” bit on directories) is still set on `/home` (and `/`):

```
david@localhost:~$ ls -l /home/david
total 732K
drwx------  1 david users 4,2K Dec 14 22:07 .
dr-xr-x--x  1 root  root    80 Nov 10 09:05 ..
drwx------  1 david users   60 Aug 24  2014 .adobe
-rw-------  1 david users   83 Dec  6 19:49 .bash_aliases
-rw-------  1 david users   66 May 12  2011 .bash_completion
-rw-------  1 david users  703 Nov 23 05:41 .bash_exports
[etc...]
```

See [Jakuje's answer](/a/710639/175814) for a possible alternative approach to your underlying aim.

Comment: @Jakuje: Done. My mistake. J and K are so close on the keyboard.

Comment: thanks for your reply David, but that still not solving the issue as users cannot type commands to move between directories, neither guess the directory path, they  are using Filezilla/WinSCP. I am a bit surprised that hiding folders from users without permission cannot be accomplish. I have also tried another way, mounting /home/company-folder into the user directory by: mount --bind /home/company-folder /home/company-folder/users/username-1 but this have to be done individually for every existing and new user, and I may need it to be done automatically when creating a new user.

Comment: My university (and many other places) mount required network drives upon login and unmount it on logout. Maybe you can use a similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any way to do what you describe, but there is `-d` option for openssh `sftp-server`, which specifies users starting directory, which can solve your problem about

> [...] to browse through the whole list of user folders to find his personal folder.

If you specify your `sftp-server` such as:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -d /users/%u
```

(you need to omit `/home/company-folder/`, since you are already chrooted there).

Comment: but they still need to access /home/company-folder/ which also contains common folders (eg. /home/company-folder/projects), so specifying starting directory like that doesn't work. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: @berriop: What about an additional user for the shared folder?

Comment: Or some default symlinks from users own directories? It is not elegant, but it should work.