# Locking a folder on a shared linux server

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, directory, lock

My college has a server set up for students and we all have a folder for our persona stuff on it (access via ssh). So I explored it a bit and found out I can access most of the folders of other students and view its contents such as text files , folders etc but of course i cant change them without the admin permission .

Then I found some folders that cant be accessed. WHen i type   "cd foldername" I get a message permission denied. So now I'm wondering can I block other people from accessing my folder on that server and how? Using console (Ubuntu 15.4) ?

Comment: You could remove read permission for others on folders that you own with `chmod`. There's a good answer by @David Foerster here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/710618/hide-dont-list-non-readable-folders?rq=1 that explains the issue.

Comment: Changing permissions would require admin privileges, and if you aren't an admin, then no, you can't change them.

Comment: @mikewhatever Well i think i have admin privileges over my own folder

Answer (score 0):

See if you can `chmod` one of your own files. Something like `chmod 600 myfile.txt` If you can do that you have control of your files. The 6 is your permission lvl the 0 for others.

Now go check from someone else if they can see your file. or you could `su <otheruser>` and try to see/interact with the file.